# How to use Azure Pipelines to remote to Azure Ubuntu Server VM then do deployment?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ubuntu-server

I would like to use Azure Ubuntu Server for deployment through Azure Pipelines. 
The flow that I want below but don't know how to do this:

When there is new update in Git-Hub dev branch, trigger Pipelines to perform:

1. Remote Azure Ubuntu Server (with UI interface)
2. Close running process in Terminal
3. Download files from Git-Hub Repository
4. Re-run process in Terminal

---

**Steps that have been done**

*Procedure to create Ubuntu Server VM in Azure Portal:*

1. Create Ubuntu Server VM in Azure Portal
2. Add inbound rule (port 3389 for RDP) [(Reference link)](https://build5nines.com/how-to-setup-an-ubuntu-linux-vm-in-azure-with-remote-desktop-rdp-access/)
3. SSH to Ubuntu Server VM like `ssh user@138.30.xx.xxx`
4. `sudo apt-get update -y`
5. `sudo apt-get upgrade -y`
6. `sudo apt-get install lxde -y`
7. `sudo apt-get install xrdp -y`
8. `/etc/init.d/xrdp start`
9. Remote through RDP from Mac/Windows (can copy files easily):
10. `sudo apt-get install -f`
11. `sudo apt-get -y install nodejs`
12. `sudo apt-get -y install npm`
13. `sudo apt-get -y install chromium-browser`
14. `sudo apt-get -y update`
15. `sudo apt-get -y upgrade`

*After Setup environment:*
Start process in Terminal with below command:
`node node.js`

Comment: There is a lack of information in this question.
You need to provide which type of application and in what type of infrastructure you are trying to deploy it.
But for you to start you will need to create different tasks, here you have a full list that Microsoft provides of different types of build, test, utility and deploy tasks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops

Comment: hi @ZetaPR, added more steps that I have done so far. Please advise.

Comment: As I am seeing for the apt-get command you are trying to deploy a webapp, can you provide more information about what are you using to serve the app? Tomcat, Apache, Nginx? 
Also, which type of app are you trying to deploy NodeJS, Angular,..? Without these information it is impossible to assist you

Comment: hi @ZetaPR, I am running NodeJS with below packages: npm install puppeteer@1.20.0 puppeteer-core@1.20.0 adal-node@0.2.0 azure-keyvault@3.0.4 azure-sb@0.11.1 azure-storage@2.10.3 http@0.0.0

Comment: Ok, but what about accesing the app for serving are you using Apache? Nginx? or what?

Comment: It is Http Server with keep checking whether have new Service Bus message or not. There is no directly UI page to be accessed.

Comment: Please check the following documentation provided by Microsoft for building and deploying NodeJS apps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks! Is it allowing for scaling as I would like to run 3-4 processes in a VM to handle tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of below three different ways to do this that you can give them a try.

1, Use SSH task to run scripts in a remote machine( Azure Ubuntu Server).

First you need to add a **SSH service connection** to your azure organization. Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) for steps how to create new service connection and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-ssh) for the settings of SSH service connection.

Then You need to create a empty build pipeline and add the SSH task. Choose the SSH service connection you have created in above step, then you can run your custom commands in the commands field. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser%2Ctfs-2018-2#get-your-first-run) for example steps to create a build pipeline. Below screenshot is in classic UI view.

[image]

2, Install a self-hosted agent on your Azure Ubuntu Server and run your build pipeline on this agent.

Firstly, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps to create a self-hosted linux agent.

Secondly, create a build pipeline and choose your self agent pool which has your self-hosted agent. So that the tasks and  commands will run on your Azure Ubuntu Server
Then you can add **bash task** to run your custom scripts. or add other tasks according to your project.

[image]

3, Create a deployment agent on your https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/deploymentgroups/

You can follow the detailed steps [here](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/deploymentgroups/) to create a deployment group and provision the agent.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-linuxvm-deploygroups?view=azure-devops&tabs=java) is simply example about how to user deployment group in your release pipeline

Addition:To enable CI build for each new update to Git-Hub dev branch. You need to enable the CI trigger in your build pipeline.
Go to the edit page your pipeline, choose **Triggers** and enable **Continuous Integration** 
[image]

Hope above helps!

Comment: For step 1 & 3, it should be okay. However, when running step 2 with Bash/SSH task with script `lxterminal --title="MyScriptWindow"`, there is error  *##[error]Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused* and *(lxterminal:22437): Gtk-WARNING **: 06:32:07.089: cannot open display:*

Comment: Is your agent running in interactive mode or as service, please have a try runing your agent [interatively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#run-interactively) if it is running as service.

Comment: It is running in interactive mode: `sudo ./svc.sh status` with output `not installed`.

Comment: Are you following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#commands)

Comment: yes, as I only need to *Run interactively*, then I only perform `./run.sh`, am I wrong?

Comment: If the agent is runing as service, i suggest you run `./config.sh remove` to remove the agent and then  ` run ./config.sh` to configure it again, and choose to run interactively during the configuration steps. Then you only need to perform `./run.sh` to start up your agent.